# How to get started with first framework - CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've decided to start my adventure with CakePHP, it'll be the first framework in my life, and I do not have many experiences with framework.

The question is, how and where should I start? For the beggining I'd like to make a easy page with subpages etc.

How should I start?

Comment: I would recommend a tutorial such as this one perhaps: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=cakephp%20quick%20and%20easy%20tutorial&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com%2Fdeveloperworks%2Fopensource%2Ftutorials%2Fos-php-cake1%2Fos-php-cake1-pdf.pdf&ei=nYCwTpqLENPisQLcp_jOAQ&usg=AFQjCNGxMOxmmmR0prE68CkTgL59VkScsA&cad=rja

Comment: Incidentally, I typically use the Zend Framework. I'm not saying it's better or worse than CakePHP but I love it, you might too!

Comment: Too much to be answered here. The best answer you'll get will tell you to read the documentation.

Comment: @mmmshuddup
Why you love it? Does it has any extras ? `:p`

Comment: No, I mean I just like their structure and style so to speak.  To me, it's much "cleaner" than Cake..  But again, that's me.

Comment: Just to explain all the downvotes, as you're quite new: SO is about asking specific questions which it is helpful for others to answer. You could answer this very easily yourself by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, look at the Getting Started documentation on their website. You can also browse their support forum/community if you have questions as you go. I also suggest reading the source of open-source scripts that also use that framework to see how things are done. If you can find a "cheat sheet", bookmark and/or print it for easy access so you can use it as you go.

EDIT: Some links...
http://book.cakephp.org/
http://ask.cakephp.org/

Answer (score 1):

You start, like with anything, by reading the documentation (optional step 1 is Googling). 
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1527/Tutorials-Examples

Answer (score 0):

The [CakePHP Cook Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/879/Beginning-With-CakePHP) is a good place to start.